# Having trouble chaining ActiveRecord::Associations record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to retrieve an associated column named "contribution_amount" for each user but I'm getting undefined method error and I can't figure out why.

Controller has:

```
@payments = Payment.where(:contribution_date => Date.today).pluck(:user_id) 
@users = User.where(:id => @payments).find_each do |user|
   user.payments.contribution_amount
end
```

models have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Exact error in console is

```
`undefined method `contribution_amount' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Payment:0x007fb89b6b2c08>`
```

Answer (score 2):

`user.payments` is a scope; that is, it represents a collection of `Payment` records.  The `contribution_amount` method is only available on individual `Payment` records. You could say `user.payments.first.contribution_amount`, but I'm not sure that's your goal.

Are you trying to sum the contribution amounts?  In that case, you'd want to use a method which aggregates collections of records: `user.payments.sum(:contribution_amount)`.

Veering off-topic for a moment, it is generally better to push scoping methods down into your models.  For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_payment_contribution_after(date)
    joins(:payments).merge(Payment.with_contribution_after(date))
  end

  def self.with_contribution_amount
    joins(:payments).group("users.id")
      .select("users.*, sum(payments.contribution_amount) as contribution_amount")
  end
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_contribution_after(date)
    where(:contribution_date => date)
  end
end

# In your controller
@users = User.with_payment_contribution_after(Date.today)
  .with_contribution_amount


# In a view somewhere
@users.first.contribution_amount
```

The advantages to structuring your code this way are:

1. Your scopes are not longer locked away in a controller method, so you can easily reuse them other places.
2. Your controller method can become simpler and more declarative.  That is, it can express *what* information it wants, not *how* that information is acquired.
3. Breaking scopes down into smaller pieces implies that our code is better decomposed, and that which has been decomposed can be recomposed.
4. It's easier to test scopes via model unit tests then via controller testing.

Comment: Followed up with some additional info.

Comment: I'm trying to get the contribution_amount for each user where a payment is due on a particular date.

Btw, Thanks for the advice on moving scoping methods to the model.